# Can I create a table and database on a slave without breaking replication?

Tags: mysql, master-slave-replication, linux

I have One Mysql master server and Slave server running on ec2. The replication is working fine. Now I need to make some changes.  I need to add new slave server to the current replication loop.

> Is it possible to add new tables and database which is not existing on master server on newly created slave.
>
> Is this affect master server ? or broke the replication ?

We are not using this slave server for fail-over. Need to analyses live data and store to another database.

> Server version: 5.5.48 MySQL Community Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not planning to switch master and you're sure the tables / databases are never going to exist in the master, you can have them without breaking replication. I have a setup like that running for some years now and working just fine.

Comment: I'm creating new slave server from existing  slave server's image and planning to add database to new slave which doesn't existing  on master, no making any change on master. I want make sure it will affect master server/db crash.